# View data of a table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I installed sql server 2008 and I can't view table data. When I rightclick on the table it shows select top 1000 rows, edit top 200 rows. How to view all the rows of my table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to view all the records in a table and there are more than 1000? In that case

```
SELECT * FROM <table name here>
```

or select the "select top 1000 rows" option and then just remove the "TOP 1000" from the query

Comment: thats fair enough... Sql erver 2005 has an option of ViewTable and that option is not there in sql server 2008

Comment: Then select the edit top 200 rows option and press "Ctrl+3" to display the query and remove the "TOP (200)" from the query and press "Ctrl+r" to re run the query

Comment: this will give you the same output as SQL 2005, they just limited the amount of data return by default in SQL 2008

Answer (score 3):

Try this,
On the menu Select Tools-> Options->SQL Server Object Explorer->Commands
**Under Table and View Options**  you can alter the default value for 
"Value for Edit  Rows command, and Value for Select Top  Rows command

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

use databasename go
select * from tablename

This might help